# My WordPress website displays http error 404

Tags: php, database, wordpress, http

please I recently migrated my site from one hosting account to another [within the same hosting provider]. Now, the site files and database file have been duly uploaded, yet the site won't come up. It keeps displaying http error 404. I have tried everything but nothing seems to work.

I use Hostinger. I have tried the 4 options I know to correct the error but nothing worked [1. connecting the domain, 2. clearing cache, 3. creating a new .htaccess file, 4. connecting the database with the wpconfig file correctly]

Please any other ideas? I'm getting frustrated...

I had tried connecting the domain, which is correct
I had tried clearing cache and using another internet
I had tried creating a new .htaccess file
I had tried connecting the database host, username, password and IP Address to the wpconfig file

All these are working properly, yet the site won't come up.

Comment: Is the 404 coming from the server (Apache, Nginx, etc.) or from WordPress? If the former, it might be easiest to contact your host's support.

Comment: @ChrisHaas Thank you for your response. Here is the message displayed 

No webpage was found for the web address: https://nubeginningconsulting.com/
HTTP ERROR 404

So I really can't tell where it's coming from. I use Hostinger. I've contacted their support team and they aren't able to fix it, telling me that the database tables might be incomplete. Meanwhile, I exported it correctly.

Comment: I can see your login page, which tells me that WordPress is at least working. I would try enabling WordPress and PHP error reporting to see if there’s an error creeping up.